# How to return only JSON from Zend

Tags: php, json, web-services, zend-framework, rest

I'm using Zend Framework 1.x for my project. I want to create a Web service return only JSON string for the caller function. I tried to use `Zend_Controller_Action` and applied those ways:

1.

```
$this->getResponse()
     ->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain')
     ->setBody(json_encode($arrResult));
```

2.

```
$this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch')
              ->addActionContext('nctpaymenthandler', 'json')
              ->initContext();
```

3.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

4.

```
$this->_response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

5.

```
echo Zend_Json::encode($arrResult);
exit;
```

6.

```
return json_encode($arrResult);
```

7.

```
$this->view->_response = $arrResult;
```

But when I used cURL to get result, it returned with JSON string surrounded by some HTML tags. Then I tried to user `Zend_Rest_Controller` with the options above. It still did not success.

P.S.: Most of those ways above are from the question which had been asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I Like this way!

```
//encode your data into JSON and send the response
$this->_helper->json($myArrayofData);
//nothing else will get executed after the line above
```

Comment: I have used this method for some time.  I don't understand the need for all the additional code.  The helper method handles everything for you as far as I can tell.

Comment: where to put this code ? In controller's action function ?

Comment: @HarisMehmood your controller's action is the right place to put it as it is its role to handle the request and prepare the output.

Answer (score 14):

You need to disable the layout and view rendering.

Explicit disable layout and view renderer:

```
public function getJsonResponseAction()
{
    $this->getHelper('Layout')
         ->disableLayout();

    $this->getHelper('ViewRenderer')
         ->setNoRender();

    $this->getResponse()
         ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    // should the content type should be UTF-8?
    // $this->getResponse()
    //      ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    // ECHO JSON HERE

    return;
}
```

If your using the json controller action helper you need to add a json context to the action. In this case the json helper will disable the layout and view renderer for you.

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->contextSwitch()
         ->addActionContext('getJsonResponse', array('json'))
         ->initContext();
}

public function getJsonResponseAction() 
{
    $jsonData = ''; // your json response

    return $this->_helper->json->sendJson($jsonData);
}
```

Comment: The Venu's method is better !

Answer (score 9):

Your code would need to disable the layout as well in order to stop the content being wrapped with the standard page template. But a much easier approach would just be:

```
$this->getHelper('json')->sendJson($arrResult);
```

the JSON helper will encode your variable as JSON, set the appropriate headers and disable the layout and view script for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->_helper->contextSwitch()
        ->addActionContext('foo', 'json')
        ->initContext('json');
}

public function fooAction()
{
    $this->view->foo = 'bar';
}
```